# RHEL 6.5 and LDAP

Tags: linux, active-directory, redhat, ldap, rhel6

I am trying to connect our Active directory server to brand new RHEL 6.5 server. I want to authenticate users using AD credentials, but I want to restrict that only certain users can login, I don't want to allow anybody from AD to connect to it. I would like to use something like this:

CN=linuxtest,OU=SecurityGroups,DC=mydomain,DC=local

but I am not sure how would I setup OU and CN. I use sssd for authentication and my `id_provider = ad`. I wanted to use `id_provider = ldap`, but that did not work at all and RHEL customer service told me to setup this way. But I want to have a little bit more control who can do what. I know I can use this to restrict `simple_allow_users = user1, user2`, but I have 400+ users, I really don't want to go and type them all. Question is how would I setup OU or CN for my search?

Comment: Are you using SSSD?

Comment: yes, RHEL support told me to use SSSD to authenticate users. Our AD server is on Windows 2008 R2 Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many different configurations, I came to the solution where I setup

```
access_provider = simple
simple_allow_groups = linuxtest
```

and this worked out the way I wanted to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have configured a RHEL 6.5 with sssd to authenticate against LDAP, and we configured the `ldap_access_filter` to check for membership of certain groups (those groups do not need to be configured as the UNIX groups for the group mapping):

```
ldap_access_filter = (|(groupmembership=cn=group1,ou=groups,o=company)(groupmembership=cn=group2,ou=groups,o=company))
```

I have searched for similar setups with AD and the equivalent directives, but all the examples I can find are always configuring the AD with `access_provider = ldap`, so that example could work...